# how do I pass parameters to cron.php in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, cron

I'm trying to set up cron using the URL method using civiCRM 5.52 on WordPress. I have all the variables for
https://example.org//plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php

but I get a 403 forbidden message.

Am I supposed to pass username, password, and site-key on the URL? What is the proper grammar for that?

Or does cron.php ask me for those?

Comment: What method are you trying to use wget, php, wpcli, cv?

Comment: At the page below, I am using (trying to use) the "URL to cron.php" method https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#choosing-a-method

Comment: I recommend that you avoid the deprecated `civicrm/bin/cron.php` method. Use the WP-CLI method if you can - it's much more reliable https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#wp-cli